# Weighting score from 0 to 1000 for set of numerical values

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am not a mathematician so I'll give my best to explain my problem. Imagine you have 5 outputs from 5 different algorithms. In the following case "good" solution has smallest value and is given as output from algorithm 4:

```
 1    2    3    4    5
76.4 22.1 10.5 2.5 180.33
```

I need a hint/idea on how to calculate score from 0 to 1000 based on "goodness" of these numerical values. Higher score should be a function of these values, where smallest values push score towards 1000.

I don't have to use all 5 values, 2 or 3 can be enough. For example, I expect an output like this:

```
score = w1*output4+w2*output3
```

or

```
score = w1*(output4/outut3)
```

These are just my thoughts, certainly there exists better solutions with linear algebra and/or polynomial regression and/or usage of different ratios.

Thanks!

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. What are you trying to do? Maybe try to give an example. Are you trying to assign a score to each algorithm or to the whole set of algorithms?

Comment: @MrYouMath I am trying to calculate score (from 0 to 1000) based on these values from all algorithms.

Comment: Do you know the range of possible outputs for the algorithms? Can you explain more about what application you're trying to use this score for?

Comment: @user326210 The output from the algorithms range from 0 to 200 (all real numerical values). I am trying to test different sets of hyperparameters for each of these algorithms; the higher the score -  the hyperparameter set is worst and this should be calculated based on outputs from algorithms like I (tried to) explain.

Comment: I need some mathematical formula that tackle relation between algorithms well, and produce a score between 0 and 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One basic option might be to compute the Euclidean norm of the outputs:

$$\text{score} = \sqrt{(O_1)^2 + (O_2)^2 + \ldots + (O_n)^2}$$

This is a nice scoring function because it has a simple functional form, nice derivatives, and is relatively easy to compute. The defect is that is maximum value is $200\sqrt{5}$ instead of $200\cdot 5 = 1000$, and that it assigns higher scores to worse values. To fix this defect, you can make a slight modification and instead use:

$$\text{score}^\prime = \sqrt{5}\cdot\sqrt{(200-O_1)^2 + (200-O_2)^2 + \ldots + (200-O_n)^2}$$

Easier still, since your values are all positive, you could just use a one-dimensional norm:

$$\text{score}^{\prime\prime} = 1000-(O_1+O_2+O_3+O_4+O_5).$$

In general, I would think about (1) how much computation you want to do, and (2) how much you value having one excellent output among several bad ones, versus having all fairly okay outputs.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! And I suppose that I could use similar techniques if I want to use values from just 3 algorithms instead of all 5?

Comment: Yes. Assuming you have $n$ possible values you want to use, all ranging from 0 to 200, you can use $$S=5\cdot n^{-1/k}\cdot\left[(200-O_1)^k+(200-O_2)^k+\ldots+(200-O_n)^k\right]^{1/k}$$ You can pick any $k>1$. Larger $k$ means you care more about the best score than the average score. In my answer, score' has $k=2$ and score'' has $k=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much again, this really helps. Just one addtional follow up question: imagine that I have different maximum values for each algorithm and that I want to use 3 out of 5 algorithms, should I use 3 instead of 5 in your equation and maximum values for each algorithm instead of 200?

Comment: Happy to help! Instead of 200, use the maximum value for each algorithm. Instead of $5\times n^{-1/k}$, use whatever value will make the score equal to 1000 if all the algorithms are as good as possible.